# EF Core - Insert then update an entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In a WebApi method I need, if an element not exist, insert it and after a few operations update it.

The code is the following:

```
Entry existingEntry = await _repo.GetEntryByIdAsync(id);

existingEntry = await _repo.AddNewEntryAsync(existingAccred);

// Some code...

// Update
existingAccred.IdField = myField;
await _repo.UpdateEntryAsync(existingEntry);
```

The repo is the following:

```
    public async Task<Entry> GetEntryByIdAsync(int myId)
    {
        var result = from entry in _ctx.Set<DALENTRY>()
            where entry.ID == myId
            select new Entry
            {
                ID = entry.IdEntry,
            };

        return await result.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Entry> AddNewEntryAsync(Entry newEntry)
    {
        DALENTRY entry = new DALENTRY()
        {
            GUID = newEntry.GUID,
        };

        _ctx.Add(entry);
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

        newEntry.IdEntry = entry.ID;

        return newEntry;
    }

    public async Task<Entry> UpdateEntryAsync(Entry updateEntry)
    {
        DALENTRY entry = new DALENTRY()
        {
            ID = updateEntry.IdEntry,
            FIELD= updateEntry.IdField,
        };

        _ctx.Update(entry);
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

        return updateEntry;
    }
```

But when I perform the update I'm getting is the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'DALENTRY' cannot
>   be tracked because another instance with the same key value for
>   {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities,
>   ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is
>   attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap.Add(TKey
>   key, InternalEntityEntry entry)

The repo is registered as Transient like:

```
services.AddTransient<EntryRepository>();
```

I tried using Detach after the insert, but using it the update is clearing all the non updated fields. I can't remember what is causing this issue.

Comment: Does the class Entry adds/updates in single table only in DB or there are multiple tables that a record is inserted, reason being one of the child entry may be locked. You have to find that and use Asnotracking while reading that entity (although this will have concurrency issue). You can use ChangeTracker.Entries() to find entries that are tracked. To ignore update of other fields you need to set IsModified to false in each property. Something like this - this.Entry(entry).Property(x => x.Property1).IsModified = false;

Comment: @RaviA. I'm already using AsNoTracking to read the entity, code added. I can't see where is the issue

Comment: Somewhere between this call and DB i believe it is still tracked. Did you try the method i suggested to find the entries that are still tracked? Most of the times its one of the child entry.

Comment: I tried is a simple object mapping one-to-one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing my update strategy in the repo by read the entry first, then update it:

```
public async Task<Entry> UpdateEntryAsync(Entry updateEntry)
{
    DALENTRY entry = await _ctx.Set<DALENTRY >().SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.ID == updateEntry.IdEntry);

    entry.FIELD= updateEntry.IdField;

    _ctx.Update(entry);
    await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

    return updateEntry;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, should you add AsNoTracking to this line  DALENTRY entry = await _ctx.Set<DALENTRY >().SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.ID == updateEntry.IdEntry); Or Update takes care of releasing change tracking?